# How to visualize efficiently million markers on a map?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, geolocation, cluster-analysis

**Context:**

I've a basic python script retrieving tweets and their location from Twitter's API with a rate of ~50 tweets/s.

These locations are sent to my express app sitting on my Google App Engine flex instance, trough Cloud Pub/Sub.

My express app is basically an endpoint that receive post requests from Pub/Sub, grab locations of each tweet and store them to the memory-cache.
Then it's using [Supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster) to generate clusters from these locations based on the current client bounding box and zoom.

**Problem:**

Supercluster is doing a great job, and I'm quite happy with the way of storing locations in the memory-cache because I'm reducing latency involved by http requests.

But, after reaching 500k locations, Supercluster is now having hard time to load all locations. (Computing is fine tho). There is around 600ms delay before sending clusters to the client.

Also, playing with 1 million of locations is taking more than a second.

**Questions:**

Is there any solution to store and query efficiently a million of locations to be able to generate clusters in less than 500ms ?

Comment: Update them, rather than recomputing them every time?